# What is the easiest way to zip output of the Build process in VSTS?

Tags: visual-studio, azure

We are trying to zip output of tthe build process in VSTS. What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even easier than using PowerShell, if you go to VSTS Marketplace there is a task/step “zip” that you can add to your VSTS tenant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a very simple PowerShell script to zip up the build results.

```
Add-Type -A System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
[IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($source, $env:FILE_NAME)
```